# Permutations using a multidict

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

I'm trying to put together a code that replaces unique characters in a given input string with corresponding values in a dictionary in a combinatorial manner while preserving the position of 'non' unique characters.

For example, I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'R':['A','G'], 'Y':['C','T']}
```

How would go about replacing all instances of 'R' and 'Y' while producing all possible combinations of the string but maintaining the positions of 'A' and 'C'?

For instance, the input 'ARCY' would generate the following output:

```
'AACC'
'AGCC'
'AACT'
'AGCT'
```

Hopefully that makes sense. If anyone can point me in the right directions, that would be great!

Comment: Use `str.replace` to substitute characters and [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for the permutations.

Comment: By unique, do you mean we only see R and Y once in the input?

Comment: Unique in the sense that characters like R and Y are replaced by multiple values while everything else remains as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) produces all of your desired strings, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) all of which are very handy `Python` tools/concepts you should read up on:

```
from itertools import product

def multi_replace(s, d):
    indexes, replacements = zip(*[(i, d[c]) for i, c in enumerate(s) if c in d])
    # indexes: (1, 3)
    # replacements: (['A', 'G'], ['C', 'T'])

    l = list(s)  # turn s into sth. mutable
    # iterate over cartesian product of all replacement tuples ...
    for p in product(*replacements):  
        for index, replacement in zip(indexes, p):
            l[index] = replacement
        yield ''.join(l)

d = {'R': ['A', 'G'], 'Y': ['C', 'T']}
s = 'ARCY'

for perm in multi_replace(s, d):
    print perm

AACC
AACT
AGCC
AGCT

s = 'RRY'

AAC
AAT
AGC
AGT
GAC
GAT
GGC
GGT
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the dictionary, we can state a rule that tells us what letters are possible at a given position in the output. If the original letter from the input is in the dictionary, we use the value; otherwise, there is a single possibility - the original letter itself. We can express that very neatly:

```
def candidates(letter):
    d = {'R':['A','G'], 'Y':['C','T']}
    return d.get(letter, [letter])
```

Knowing the candidates for each letter (which we can get by `map`ping our `candidates` function onto the letters in the pattern), we can create the Cartesian product of candidates, and collapse each result (which is a tuple of single-letter strings) into a single string by simply `''.join`ing them.

```
def substitute(pattern):
    return [
        ''.join(result)
        for result in itertools.product(*map(candidates, pattern))
    ]
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> substitute('ARCY')
['AACC', 'AACT', 'AGCC', 'AGCT']
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ARCY` to multiple list and use below code:

```
import itertools as it
list = [['A'], ['A','G'],['C'],['C','T']]
[''.join(item) for item in it.product(*list)]
```

or

```
import itertools as it
list = ['A', 'AG','C', 'CT']
[''.join(item) for item in it.product(*list)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the values from a dictionary instead of listing it out? If I expand the input to say 15 characters, this method would become very tedious.

Comment: Take empty list, then iterate each character from input string and check if key(each character) exists in dictionary and append value to your initial list if match found, if no match found then append [current character] to your initial list. It will not be tedious even if input string length is high.